# Multipart request is failing with error "Required argument [CompletedFileUpload attachment] not specified" on AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data, micronaut

We have Upload service lambda which is integrated to API gateway exposing rest API endpoint.
AWS lambda has 6 MB limit on file being upload , so we decided to use multipart restful upload request which seems to solve the problem.
When we tested this in local it works and uploads the file on S3, so we know our client call and controller are correct.
But when I deploy the code as lambda the multipart Http request fails saying.

```
{
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "<PATH to API gateway resource> ",
            "templated": false
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Required argument [CompletedFileUpload attachment] not specified",
                "path": "/attachment"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Controller code :

```
@Post(value = "/attachments/{id}", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public HttpResponse<String> upload(@Part("attachment") CompletedFileUpload attachment, @PathVariable String id) {
....
}
```